# Configuring an Image Asset

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I already set up my app's build.gradle to use minSdkVersion 26. Android Studio keeps complaining about the minimal version of sdk when creating an image asset
[image: build.gradle]

[image: Configure Image Asset]

Answer (score 0):

@thamibn solve my question on github! Tanks https://github.com/thamibn

[answare](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3512)

"@rafahead open android studio File->Open folder->navigate to your flutter project and select the Android folder. Wait for it to sync, then navigate inside the Android studio folder and find the res folder right click on it and choose New you will see the Image asset studio."